# Eager loading polymorfic relation's related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my app I have a wall with posts.

Every post can have attachments, like `Video` or `Product` (and many another types, so making separate relations for every type will be a bad idea).

Here is database structure example:

```
videos
    id
    ...

products
    id
    ...

product_photos
    product_id
    ...

posts
    id
    ...

post_attachments
    post_id
    attachment_id
    attachment_type
```

In `Post` model I defined relation to `PostAttachment`:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function attachments()
    {
        $this->hasMany(PostAttachment::class);
    }
}
```

In `PostAttachment` model I defined polymorphic relation to attachment:

```php
class PostAttachment extends Model
{
    public function attachment()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

If I want to get entire wall, i can do something like this:

```php
$posts = Post::with([
    'attachments',
    'attachments.attachment'
])->get();
```

which results in:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "attachments": [
            {
                ...
                "attachment_type": "App\Models\Video",
                "attachment": {
                    "id": 101,
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                ...
                "attachment_type": "App\Models\Product",
                "attachment": {
                    "id": 203,
                    ...
                }
            },

        ]
    }
]
```

But what if I want to include a `Product` photos in result?
I can't do something like that:

```php
$posts = Post::with([
    'attachments',
    'attachments.attachment',
    'attachments.attachment.photos'
])->get();
```

because `photos` relation is only exists in `Product` model, not in `Video`.

Dirty solution is to include relation loading in model definition:

```php
class Product
{
    protected $with = [
        'photos'
    ];

    ...
}
```

But with this solution photos will be returned even if I get `Product` model directly.

How can I load `Product` photos only when I showing wall?

Many thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Laravel 5.8.22 or higher** you could use ***Nested Eager Loading morphTo Relationships***.`

See [docuemntation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;


$posts = Post::query;

$posts = $posts->with([
    'attachments.attachment' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
                $morphTo->morphWith([
                    Product::class => ['photos'],
                    //add more if any
                ]);
            }]);

$posts = $posts->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that I looked at the old documentation before, therefore I did not find this